# How do I configure Sinatra to use structure.sql instead of schema.rb?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, database-schema

I've got a Sinatra app that I'm setting up with a database using ActiveRecord.

Due to one of the quirks of this database (namely a string primary key), I want to use a SQL schema (`structure.sql`) instead of a Ruby one (`schema.rb`). I don't mind that this restricts me to using a specific database flavour, we use Postgres for everything anyway.

To achieve this in Rails, I would put `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in `config/application.rb`. How do I do the same thing in Sinatra?

Comment: This isn't a Sinatra question, it'd be an ActiveRecord question. Sinatra is just an innocent bystander.

Comment: You might want to look at using Padrino. It sits on top of Sinatra but provides a lot of Rails-like generators and helpers. Sinatra is wonderful and can work with a DBM but you'll end up writing more code.

Comment: This _is_ a Sinatra question, because while it's easy to find out how to do it in the Rails framework (as stated above), that doesn't apply to Sinatra - or if it does, there's a lot of manual setup to _make_ it apply.

Comment: No, Sinatra has absolutely no ties to DBMs. You have to incorporate your choice of database connectivity. Typically we do that using Sequel or DataMapper, though ActiveRecord can do it too. Still, Sinatra has no idea of a database, only those other gems do. There are no methods in Sinatra that would care, only the underlying Ruby language. Sinatra is a DSL specifically for creating the URL handlers only. Rails, on the other hand, is tightly coupled to ActiveRecord and expects DB connectivity to function. But this isn't a Rails question, nor is a Sinatra question as a result.

Comment: Check the [README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html), which covers the DSL well. It's really important to understand what parts of your code do what, especially when asking about that code on SO.

Comment: You're getting far too technical. The only real relevance of Sinatra is _that it is not Rails,_ so I don't have the same config framework that people might otherwise expect from an ActiveRecord app. Here's the essence of the question again: "I'm running a [non-Rails] ActiveRecord app; I want to use a SQL schema instead of a Ruby one. How?"

Comment: Correct. Which is what I edited the title and question to say before you rolled it back.

Comment: Yeah, but most people think 'Rails' when they see 'ActiveRecord'. I'm less of a pedant than you are, and I'm supplying the specifics of my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to configure your database by hand with Sinatra.  We like to build our tables in MySQL instead of using ActiveRecord Migrations.

You'll have to create your database models by hand instead of using generators and you'll add this line to manage your connection:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(database_settings)
```

This is super easy.  We typically read in the settings from a YAML file. It gets complicated when you want to write automated tests.  Here's a blog I wrote about [how to set up automated tests with Sinatra, MiniTest, and ActiveRecord](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-i-test-ruby-apis-in-a-non-rails-environment-718aba24b189#.inwj0dqfi).

Comment: You're not setting up Sinatra to do it, you're setting up ActiveRecord to do it. Sinatra is only a DSL for handling URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are still using active record, you can just add next line to your config (I put it under `config/initializers/active_record.rb`).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format = :sql
```